# Adding powers of exponential equation in python

Tags: python, sympy

I'm new to Python, just started two days back. I was trying to perform division on two exponential expressions but the output won't show the powers added.

Following is my code.

```
from sympy import integrate, symbols, exp
from IPython.display import display, Markdown

x, y = symbols('x,y', positive=True)

fxy = y*exp(-y*(x+1))
fy= exp(-y)

sol = fxy/fy

sol
```

Comment: Can you include the output you get as well as what you expect the output to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're looking for `simplify`:

```
>>> sympy.simplify(y * exp(-y*(x +1)) / exp(-y))                           
y*exp(-x*y)
```

Comment: Yes - This worked. Thank you. I was going through the Python documentation but couldn't get this, even though I knew this should be there somewhere.